# Crash at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Tags: java, android, dalvik

Just got error report at Google Play (ex. Android Market) publisher interface.

Here is **full** stacktrace:

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

That's it. As far as I understand it crashed without even reaching my code. Is there something I should do or should I simply ignore this error? How could this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore it, there's nothing you can do. In some cases, you'll get an `OutOfMemoryError` with a reasonable stack trace. These are actionable. What you've pasted isn't.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. Seen a longer stack traces includin my package names in them before.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is an error not related to your app. It is related to the system (phone system) not able to handle the processes running on it in terms of memory. And your process gets selected to be the victim to kill.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps You would have forgot add your destination activity in manifest file.
Adding Activity in Manifest Worked for me.